# Android RECOGNIZE_SPEECH_ACTIVITY For problem (for?)

Tags: java, android

Having made this method, I was trying to Brake the string (strSpeech2Text) in chars, and assign them each on T1 T2 etc, Texts views.

If I don't try to reuse the foreach, to do that, what I get is that the whole word is assigned to each text view. So asigning works..

What is wrong with that?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RECOGNIZE_SPEECH_ACTIVITY:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> speech = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                String strSpeech2Text = speech.get(0);
                grabar.setText(strSpeech2Text);


                TextView T1;
                T1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TIRADA0);
                TextView T2;
                T2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TIRADA1);
                TextView T3;
                T3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TIRADA2);
                TextView T4;
                T4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TIRADA3);



                //String v;
                String a = strSpeech2Text;
                int n = 0;
                for (TextView i : Arrays.asList(T1, T2, T3, T4)) {
                    Character v = a.charAt(n);
                    i.setText(Character.toString(v));
                    n++;
                }


            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. I didn't test it but it looks good to me:

```
ArrayList<TextView> textViews = Arrays.asList(T1, T2, T3, T4);    

for (int i=0; i<textViews.size() && strSpeech2Text.length>i; i++) {
    textViews.get(i).setText(strSpeech2Text.substring(i,i+1));
}
```